# Wordpress CMS roles and privacy

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress and can't fit in it's concepts in my mind. Basically I want to turn my Wordpress into something like social networking i.e a wordpress blog owner is a single person in normal circumstances and he may have other person with other roles like editor etc. But I do not need that. What I need is more of a social networking website where each person may have their post and each person is a administrator of his own account. Administrator A can't delete some other administrator B's post.

I hope you are getting my use case. Can I do that in Wordpress? Any hints would be helpful. If any built in functionality/plugin is available please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform WordPress from a blog/CMS into a Social Network you'll need to install the plugin called [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/). It's built by the same creators of WordPress and it does what you need.

Comment: Actually for now I've chosen the option to create wordpress network: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network Do you think that too can do the job?

Comment: Yes using Multi-Site will work if your goal is to create http://wordpress.com, each member who would signup can create their own blog which would be installed at bloguser.yourdomain.com or yourdomain.com/bloguser. However you did say you wanted a social network so BuddyPress fits your needs while using WordPress Multisite will create a Blog Network. Either way, have fun!